# Moving a file from a PC to an Android-readable location

Tags: android, file-io

I am creating a simple Android app.  To run properly, it needs the contents of a file (`example.xml`) that is currently on my PC.

On creation, the app would look for the file, and then do some stuff with it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...
    File file = new File("I wish I knew what to put here");
    doStuffWithFile(file);
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know where to put the file.

I need a location in internal storage to which both my PC and my Android app have access.

Is there such a location?  If so, what file path `String` would I use to access it?

Comment: Ignore the PC for the moment. When you distribute this app to others, how will they get this file? Do you want it to be "baked into" the app, so it ships when the app does? Will they download the file from a Web server through your app? Will you be expecting them to copy the file from their PC to their device? If you can tell us that, we can better advise you in terms of a direction.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I would expect the file to be on the user's PC.  Eventually I will build a separate application for PC that builds and moves the file onto the Android device.  For now, I just need to know where to put it so I can focus on the Android side of things.

Comment: Then beta's answer of using the `Downloads/` on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is a reasonable approach. `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` returns a `File`, from which you can create other `File` objects for individual files, subdirectories, etc. Note that you need to hold the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to read the contents of that directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Download folder by using `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`

Then you can add a filename and use this e.g. with [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could include the file in the [`assets`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) folder of your project and then retrieve it with `this.getContext().getAssets().open("example.xml")`